# Lotus Notes - Append only one value from .OpenFileDialog into a field

Tags: field, lotus-notes

Here's my code:

```
Set item=doc.GetFirstItem("Path_1")
Set item1=doc.GetFirstItem("Path") ' Path is a multiple value field.

filenames = ws.OpenFileDialog(True, "Select",, "")
    If Not(Isempty(filenames)) Then
        Forall filename In filenames
            item1.AppendToTextList(filename) 'Path contains all the paths selected.
        End Forall
    End If
```

What I want to do is to add the filepath selected from the OpenDialog into Path_1, but not all of them. Eg: Path1 selected => Path contains Path1. After this, Path2 is selected => Path contains Path2. ( overwrite ... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: The first parameter of "OpenFileDialog" stands for multiple selection. If you just want to select ONE file, then just set this to false.

filenames will still be an array, but just with one entry.

Second: If you want to set ONE value to an item, then use replaceitemvalue of NotesDocument or just the value property of the item:

Replace:

```
    Forall filename In filenames
        item.AppendToTextList(filename) 'Path contains all the paths selected.
    End Forall
```

with:

```
    item.values = filenames(0)
```

or:

```
    doc.ReplaceItemValue( "Path", filenames(0) )
```

or:

```
    item.text = filenames(0)
```

And some other thing: 
First of all: Use `Option declare` in ALL of your code, it makes life much easier. 
Then: You define item1 twice: First it takes the item "Path_1" and directly after that you assign it the item "Path"... That makes no sense as you do not even use item, when it is assigned to "Path_1"...

Just to have a complete solution here: For me the code would look like:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim itemPath as NotesItem
Dim varFiles as Variant

Set doc = .... 'somehow set the doc
Set itemPath = doc.GetFirstItem( "Path" )

varFiles = ws.OpenFileDialog(False, "Select",, "")
If not isempty( varFiles ) then
    '- Just Write the LAST value into Path_1
    call doc.ReplaceItemValue( "Path_1" , varFiles(0) )
    '- Append the selected value to the path "History"
    itemPath.AppendToTextList( varFiles(0) )
End If
```

Comment: THanks for your response! Yes indeed, I want to select only one file per time, but if user make 3 consecutive selections I want to put all the 3 paths into a multiple value field( "Path" ) Also, the current selection I want to keep it into a text field. ( "Path_1" ). Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: All you need was already in my post above. Nevertheless I modified it a little to contain all code you need (no more need for you to think, what normally is not the intention of a platform like stackoverflow)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your advice! I'm newbie in LN programming, and I can ensure you that I made some research before posting this question. I accept anyway your irony and sarcasm as well as your advices and help! Have a nice day!